# Django how to call a function in another class from django admin section

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

hi recently I have implemented a temp django model and I want this to get populate when the user clicks it from django admin

this is the implementation in django admin

```
            from django.contrib import admin
            from polls.models import Poll
            from polls.models import TempModel
            from django.conf.urls import patterns
            from django.http import HttpResponse
            from test_data import TestData
            from django.http import HttpResponse
            from django.template import RequestContext, loader
            from test_data import TestData


            class  TempModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
                fields = ('permalink', )

                def test(self):
                    x = TestData.get_test_data()


            admin.site.register(Poll)
            admin.site.register(TempModel, TempModelAdmin)
```

and this is the temporary class which I used to populate data

```
            from models import   TempModel

            class TestData(object):
                @classmethod
                def get_test_data(self):
                    print "**********************************************"
                    print "get test data"
                    print "**********************************************"
                    list = []
                    for x in range(0,50):
                        str_val =  str(x) + "djdj;djfhdfjiosdifj";
                        list.append(str_val)
                        temp_model = TempModel()
                        temp_model.permalink = str_val
                        temp_model.save()
                    print "=============================================="
                    print "Object Count"
                    print TempModel.objects.count()
                    print "=============================================="
                    return list
```

this is not getting called . Can anyone know the reason for this ?
Thank you in advace

Comment: and... where is `TempModelAdmin.test` method being called?

Comment: thats what I want to know how to call it?

Comment: maybe that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

Comment: Thank you though that is not the issue here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by doing this approach and it worked

```
            class  TempModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
                fields = ('permalink', )

                def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                    super(TempModelAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                    self.my_method()

                def my_method(self):
                    print "*************----------------------------"
                    TestData.get_test_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making a class method with self, it takes an instance of type. Try changing method signature:

```
def get_test_data(cls):
```